# Как в ListView если отсутствуют данные сделать надпись по центру?

Tags: java, android, listview

Как в `ListView` если отсутствуют данные сделать надпись по центру "для начала работы нажмите кнопку добавить." ?

Comment: Скройте `ListView` и сделайте на его месте надпись.

Comment: у `ListView` есть метод [`setEmptyView()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28188185/7566397)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В xml разметке определите вместе c `ListView` `TextView`

```
<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/empty_text_view"
    android:text="Пусто"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"/>
```

Далее в `onCreate()`

```
    View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty_text_view);
    ListView list = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    list.setEmptyView(empty);
```